# How to Convert 3D object (.obj) into .java file in vuforia android.?

Tags: android

i develop a new Augmented Reality Application In Android. and i want to .java file for 3d object. I need help.

How to Convert 3D object (.obj) of unity file into .java file.

Answer (score 0):

Using OpenGL ES directly is not recommended, you should integrate a 3D rendering library like libgdx (or rajawali).

For libgdx, you can open the .obj file in blender, export to fbx or/and use libgdx converter to convert to G3DB file format which is optimized for rendering.